# Access fail on sub or function

Tags: ms-access

When running this ACCESS program am getting a fail here  on NEWUpdate: 'Sub or Function not defined. I am clicking on Import button to import an excel file needed.

```
Private Sub cmdImport_Click()
NewUpdate
Me.Requery
Me.cboDts.Requery
Me.cboBiller.Requery
```

this is the complete.

```
Public Function DoFilter()
Dim mystr As String
mystr = "1=1"
If IsNull(Me.cboDept) = False Then
    mystr = mystr & " and [Description] = '" & Me.cboDept & "'"
End If
If IsNull(Me.cboDts) = False Then
    mystr = mystr & " and [Service_Date] = #" & Format(Me.cboDts, "m/d/yy") & "#"
End If
If IsNull(Me.cboBiller) = False Then
    mystr = mystr & " and [Operator] = '" & Me.cboBiller & "'"
End If
If Me.chkNotBilled = True Then
    mystr = mystr & " and [Billing_Date] Is Null"
End If
Me.Filter = mystr
Me.FilterOn = True
End Function


Private Sub cmdImport_Click()
NewUpdate
Me.Requery
Me.cboDts.Requery
Me.cboBiller.Requery

End Sub

Private Sub cmdPrint_Click()
If Me.Dirty Then DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
If Me.FilterOn = True Then
    DoCmd.OpenReport "rptPreprinted", acViewPreview, , Me.Filter
Else
    DoCmd.OpenReport "rptPreprinted", acViewPreview
End If
End Sub

Private Sub cmdRefresh_Click()
Me.Requery
End Sub

Private Sub cmdShowAll_Click()
Me.Filter = ""
Me.FilterOn = False
Me.cboDept = Null
Me.cboDts = Null
Me.cboBiller = Null
Me.chkNotBilled = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

`NewUpdate` function does not exist in the list of standard Access functions and common libraries, this is custom function and it should be defined somewhere. If you copied this code from somewhere, please search for definition of this function of define it by yourself.